# transfer subscription reporting service

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Would you recommend the best and easy way to transfer (or copy) the subscriptions from one reporting service to another reporting service in different server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How many subscriptions are there?

If theres a low number easiest thing would be to recreate them manually on the other server.

If we are talking a fair amount then there is a database reporting services to store the subscription data I believe called dbo.Subscriptions. I would recommend looking there first to see if you can see the subscriptions.

Otherwise if you would be looking to transfer the whole reporting server database (schedules included) then the following link might be of use:

[MSDN Moving the Report Server Databases to Another Computer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156421.aspx)

Comment: Hi.. i checked the subscription table and it contains 45 rows.. I cannot move the entire reporting service to another server as it will overwrite the exisiting reports in the target server. Can I just get the subscription table and re-insert rows to the target server?

Comment: Yep should be easy enough to do, but unsure if it would be locked from modification as it is a system database, check your under the correct permissions role first.
Copy and paste would be a good simple solution otherwise and you will need to do an import/export of the data:
Right Click the DB > Tasks > Import/Export and the wizard will guide you though, heres a good link: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3580216/SQL-Server-2005-Import--Export-Wizard.htm

Comment: Hi did this.. done the full backup of report server db and restored it to destination db.. but when i clicked on My Subscription on report server nothing showed.. then I queried the database and it showed 45 rows in subscription table.. do you know why it is not showing up?

Comment: sorry.. fixed it.. the users table in report server db still pointing to the windows account of old server (e.g. oldserver\windowsaccount --> changed to newserver\windowsaccount)

Answer (score 11):

Building on the answer from @S.Juarez, this script fixes his bug that breaks the parameters (and thus prevents subscriptions from working), and also transfers across the related Schedules and Schedule User records.  It maintains the same GUIDs across both source and target.

The starting point for using this script is after you have already transferred the reports (for example using the tool [ReportSync](https://github.com/dapaxx/reportsync)), and you have manually configured the security on all your report folders on the target server. You also need to decide which User record on the target server to associate Subscriptions with, for those cases where the UserName exists on the source server and not on the target server. (This can happen in situations where you decide not to recreate Users on the target, or when you cannot do so because that person no longer a valid account on the domain - i.e. they have left your organisation).

Before you begin, I'd recommend running this small script against both your source and target ReportServer databases and saving the results. Also, take full backups of the databases as whole. These steps give you the ability to rollback both small and large changes.

```
SELECT u.UserName, c.Path, Parameters, s.ExtensionSettings, s.Report_OID, SubscriptionID, u.UserID
FROM dbo.[Subscriptions] s
JOIN users u 
on s.OwnerID = u.UserID
JOIN catalog c
on c.ItemID = s.Report_OID
```

The first part of this next script will transfer the Subscriptions, followed by the Schedules and then the linking records between the Reports, Subscriptions and Schedules. You need to put in the name of your target and source servers, the name of your default user (must already exist in the target Users table) and then execute this on the source server.

```
DECLARE @Default_User varchar(50) 
SELECT @Default_User = UserID FROM [SourceServer].ReportServer.dbo.Users WHERE UserName = '[DOMAIN\YourDefaultUserNameGoesHere]'

INSERT INTO [TargetServer].ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions(
    SubscriptionID, OwnerID, Report_OID,  Locale, InactiveFlags, ExtensionSettings, ModifiedByID, ModifiedDate, 
    [Description], LastStatus, EventType, MatchData, LastRunTime, [Parameters], DataSettings, DeliveryExtension, Version
    )
SELECT 
    --cSource.Path,
    --uSource.UserName,
    SubscriptionID,
    --u.UserName,
    --LastStatus,
    COALESCE(uTarget.UserID, @Default_User) AS OwnerID,
    cTarget.ItemID,
    Locale, InactiveFlags, ExtensionSettings,
    @Default_User AS ModifiedByID,
     GETDATE(),
    sSource.[Description], LastStatus, EventType, MatchData, LastRunTime, [Parameters], DataSettings, DeliveryExtension, Version

FROM [SourceServer].ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions sSource
    LEFT JOIN [SourceServer].ReportServer.dbo.Catalog cSource ON cSource.ItemId = sSource.Report_OID
    LEFT JOIN [SourceServer].ReportServer.dbo.Users uSource ON sSource.OwnerID = uSource.UserID
    LEFT JOIN [TargetServer].ReportServer.dbo.Catalog cTarget ON cTarget.Path = cSource.Path
    LEFT JOIN [TargetServer].ReportServer.dbo.Users uTarget ON uTarget.UserName = uSource.UserName
WHERE sSource.SubscriptionID NOT IN 
(
SELECT SubscriptionID FROM [TargetServer].ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions
)


INSERT INTO [TargetServer].ReportServer.dbo.Schedule
(
ScheduleID, Name, StartDate, Flags, NextRunTime, LastRunTime, EndDate, RecurrenceType, MinutesInterval, DaysInterval, WeeksInterval, DaysOfWeek, DaysOfMonth, [Month], MonthlyWeek, State, LastRunStatus, ScheduledRunTimeout, EventType, EventData, Type, ConsistancyCheck, Path, CreatedById
)
SELECT
ScheduleID, Name, StartDate, Flags, NextRunTime, LastRunTime, EndDate, RecurrenceType, MinutesInterval, DaysInterval, WeeksInterval, DaysOfWeek, DaysOfMonth, [Month], MonthlyWeek, State, LastRunStatus, ScheduledRunTimeout, EventType, EventData, Type, ConsistancyCheck, Path, 
COALESCE(uTarget.UserID, @Default_User) AS CreatedById
FROM [SourceServer].ReportServer.dbo.Schedule s
INNER JOIN [SourceServer].ReportServer.dbo.Users uSource
ON s.CreatedById = uSource.UserID
LEFT JOIN [TargetServer].ReportServer.dbo.Users uTarget
ON uSource.UserName = uTarget.UserName
WHERE ScheduleID NOT IN (SELECT ScheduleID FROM [TargetServer].ReportServer.dbo.Schedule)


INSERT INTO [TargetServer].ReportServer.dbo.ReportSchedule
(
ScheduleID, ReportID, SubscriptionID, ReportAction
)
SELECT
    rsSource.ScheduleID, cTarget.ItemID, rsSource.SubscriptionID, rsSource.ReportAction
FROM [SourceServer].ReportServer.dbo.ReportSchedule rsSource
INNER JOIN [TargetServer].ReportServer.dbo.Schedule sTarget
ON rsSource.ScheduleID = sTarget.ScheduleID
INNER JOIN [SourceServer].ReportServer.dbo.Catalog cSource
On cSource.ItemID = rsSource.ReportID
INNER JOIN [TargetServer].ReportServer.dbo.Catalog cTarget
ON cSource.Path = cTarget.Path
LEFT JOIN [TargetServer].ReportServer.dbo.ReportSchedule rsTarget
ON  rsSource.ScheduleID = rsTarget.ScheduleID
AND rsSource.ReportID = rsTarget.ReportID
AND rsSource.SubscriptionID = rsTarget.SubscriptionID
WHERE rsTarget.ReportID IS NULL
```

To test if your migration has worked properly, you can execute a statement like this against the target server. The GUID should be a SubscriptionID from the Subscriptions table, ideally for something that will be delivered to your inbox.

```
exec [ReportServer].dbo.AddEvent @EventType='TimedSubscription', @EventData='cb38a708-7735-4b5a-8ff3-e03ee1b18edb'
```

If it works, then you should receive an email within ~20 seconds. If it fails, I found that the best place to look for troubleshooting information was in the SSRS log files, [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19397671/914490).

Comment: I am planning to migrate subscriptions from one server to another. As SSRS manages schedules by creating jobs, will simply creating records in tables in your script create working subscription schedules? In your case, you have manually triggered a schedule by creating entry in `AddEvent` table.

Comment: Hmm - good question. I no longer work at the place where I did the report migration, so I cannot check how the schedules/jobs got sorted sorry - it was a while ago. I do recall though that there were no complaints about subscriptions after the migration, so I presume that means that all was ok (either that or people didn't notice the lack of reports arriving... which I think would be unlikely given that we're talking about hundreds of subscriptions - someone would have spoken up).

Comment: Note that when going from SSRS in SharePoint 2013 to PBIRS you'll need to use "COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT" on a couple of the joins.

Comment: I got this working with some tweaks and an additional script for migrating the data-driven subscriptions.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something we used to copy subscriptions from a 2008 SSRS to a 2012 SSRS Server.  You'll need the data sources to be setup properly ahead of time.

```
INSERT INTO Mercury.ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions(SubscriptionID, OwnerID, Report_OID,  Locale, InactiveFlags, ExtensionSettings, ModifiedByID, ModifiedDate, Description, LastStatus, EventType, MatchData, LastRunTime, Parameters, DataSettings, DeliveryExtension, Version)
SELECT 
    --Path,
    SubscriptionID
    ,(SELECT UserID FROM <Destination Linked Server>.ReportServer.dbo.Users WHERE UserName = '<User from DB>')  OwnerID
    ,(select ItemId from <Destination Linked Server>.ReportServer.dbo.Catalog mCatalog where mCatalog.Path = Catalog.Path )Report_OID
    ,Locale, InactiveFlags, ExtensionSettings
    ,(SELECT UserID FROM <Destination Linked Server>.ReportServer.dbo.Users WHERE UserName = 'User from DB') ModifiedByID
    , GETDATE()
    ,Sub.Description, LastStatus, EventType, MatchData, LastRunTime, Parameter, DataSettings, DeliveryExtension, Version

FROM ReportServer..Subscriptions Sub
    LEFT JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Catalog ON Catalog.ItemId = Sub.Report_OID
WHERE Path NOT IN 
  (
    SELECT Path
    FROM <Destination Linked Server>.ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions
      LEFT JOIN <Destination Linked Server>.ReportServer.dbo.Catalog ON Catalog.ItemId = Subscriptions.Report_OID
  )
--AND
--  PATH LIKE '...'
```

Comment: Be aware the column name 'Parameter' is incorrect in the SELECT, it should be 'Parameters'.  I've added a more comprehensive answer that includes the related tables.